# How to pass parameters to spark-SQL, not spark-scala?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to run `spark-sql` from command line with a parameter:

```
$ spark-sql myscript.sql hdfs://mydir/myfile.tsv
```

In `myscript.sql` the parameter should be used

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH $PARAM1 INTO TABLE T;
```

PS: I know how to do that in `spark-shell` and `spark-submit`. But that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: `spark-sql --help` didn't help ?

Comment: I don't see from `spark-sql --help` how to use the params in the SQL script (see `INPATH $PARAM1`).

Answer (score 1):

Pass a parameter by `-d` option in `spark-sql`. You can pass multiple params using several -d.

```
$ spark-sql -d INPUT=hdfs://mydir/myfile.tsv
```

Then you can use this `INPUT` variable in SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ID              STRING,
    VALUE           STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "separatorChar" = "\,",
    "quoteChar"     = "\""
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '${INPUT}' INTO TABLE MyTable;
```